# Vue function as a prop in a v-for doesnt work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So i have a list Item component:

```
<template>
  <div
    @click="customEvent"
    class="m-3 mx-auto flex h-fit max-h-fit w-fit cursor-pointer flex-nowrap gap-5 whitespace-nowrap rounded-3xl border-2 border-gray-200 px-14 py-2 font-semibold shadow-xl transition-all duration-300 hover:scale-105 hover:bg-black hover:text-white hover:shadow-2xl"
  >
    <Icon :icon="icon" width="30" height="30" />
    {{ name }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Icon } from '@iconify/vue'
import { defineEmits } from 'vue'
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const props = defineProps({
  icon: String,
  name: String
})
const emits = defineEmits('customEvent')
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

The list items are stored in objects, they have diffretn name, icon and call diffren funtion how to make it work using v-for?

```
const sideNavbarListItems = reactive([
  {
    name: 'Resources',
    icon: 'clarity:atom-solid',
    fun: fun1
  },
  {
    name: 'Favorites',
    icon: 'tabler:stars',
    fun: fun2
  }
])
```

and i dont want to have it like

```
<side-navbar-list-item :icon="item.icon" :name="item.name" @click="fun1"></side-navbar-list-item>
<side-navbar-list-item :icon="item.icon" :name="item.name" @click="fun2"></side-navbar-list-item>
<side-navbar-list-item :icon="item.icon" :name="item.name" @click="fun3"></side-navbar-list-item>
```

i want to have it like @click="item.fun" but it doesnt work

Comment: The question lacks clear problem statement, what do you want to achieve? What's  userStore.setComponent and how is "route" supposed to work? "I tried" - this is pseudocode, please, post the actual one. "Vue function as a prop" - which function do you mean?

Comment: hey, I edited the whole question. I hope now it is more understanable. Thanks for answers and for help!

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem here. Is it v-for syntax or else? Should be something like `<side-navbar-list-item v-for="item of sideNavbarListItems" :key="item.name" :icon="item.icon" :name="item.name" @click="item.fun()">`